# Pagination in CakePHP for API

Tags: php, api, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I'm having problems developing my API in CakePHP.

I'm creating an app for android which have to query my API for data in JSON format. There are more than a thousand records in the table, so I have to paginate.

What I want is to send a request for the first 50 records of the table, load them in a list and when the user reachs the end of the list I want to send another request for the next 50 records. I know how to get the first 50 records calling index(), but I don't know how to make the request for the next 50 records. I'm new to cakephp and php, it might be easy but I can't figure it out. Maybe I'm not doing it the right way. Any help or link would be appreciate.

This is my code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use App\Controller\Api\AppController;

class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
   public $paginate = [
   'page' => 1,
   'limit' => 50,
   'maxLimit' => 50,
   'fields' => [
       'id', 'title', 'user_id'
   ],
   'sortWhitelist' => [
       'id', 'title', 'user_id'
   ]
   ];

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
}


public function index()
{
    $articles = $this->paginate($this->Articles->find('all'));
    $this->set([
        'articles' => $articles,
        '_serialize' => ['articles']
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: how about `/articles/index.json?page=2`

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you very much, I'm a newbie in web development.